How to add border to non-transparent part of a image in jetpack compose?
Let say I have an image with transparent background like this.

Sometimes I need to show it in my app on a black background, but it is indistinguishable. So I want to add a white border to the non-transparent part only like this.

The only way I can think of is making two versions of the same picture in Photoshop and show the right one based on background color. Modifier.background() just give a square border of entire image. I wonder if there is any way to solve the problem programmatically using jetpack compose without preparing two pictures.

Extracting an outline from an arbitrary image is neither easy to implement nor to calculate, so it will potentially have a noticable performance impact. I would highly suggest to just create 2 different drawables, one filled and one with just the outline and then switch between the 2 as needed

Is your image a vector image or a bitmap?

@Leviathan it's a bitmap.
